# win-sshfs vs Dokan

Tags: windows, ssh, sshfs, dokan

I'm using [win-sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) from some time. But while exploring its sources I discovered [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) project which is used by win-sshfs. But apparently it can be used by its own to do the same.

So the question is then what is the difference between those two? What values does win-sshfs add?

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to auto mount the drive when you login.

Comment: Provide more than just one line, please.