# Native Windows 10 support for sshfs

Tags: windows-10, sshfs

What (if any) native Windows-10 sshfs support is available?

I am aware of [sshfs-win](https://medium.com/@danielmarinomirallestaset/mounting-linux-fs-in-windows-10-using-sshfs-e29c7ca81c87) on [Github](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/releases/tag/v2.7.17334).

Comment: Have a look here....https://superuser.com/questions/946879/mounting-a-remote-filesystem-on-windows-10-using-bash

Comment: Also this....https://superuser.com/questions/666567/win-sshfs-vs-dokan?rq=1